# Remove CR using powershell

Tags: powershell

I was using the below command to remove the `CR` via PowerShell. It is unable to remove the last CR at the end.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve the last line issue?

PowerShell script command:

```
$path = "C:\Model\2104261054.txt"

(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","`n") | Set-Content $path -Force
```

This is how it looks after removing the `CR`:

[image: Removing CR in a file]

Comment: Add switch `-NoNewline` to the Set-Content cmdlet.I would also change the ``.Replace("`r`n","`n")`` into ``-replace '\r?\n', "`n"`` to use a regex replace, but that is trivial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string method `.TrimEnd()` to remove the last whitespaces from the text. Then save it using `Set-Content` with switch `-NoNewline` to prevent it from appending an extra newline to the file:

```
$path = "C:\Model\2104261054.txt"

((Get-Content -Path $path -Raw) -replace '\r?\n',"`n").TrimEnd() | Set-Content -Path $path -Force -NoNewline
```